Unity Shifting UI elements depending on if they are instantiated in start or update?
I have a simple system for generating an inventory screen using basic prefabs, however, depending on where the inventory item is instantiated the gameobject shifts like the image below. (top item in inventory was in the inventory before running and the second during play.)
enter image description here
Below here is the script incharge of instatiating everything. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is different
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Unity.VisualScripting;

public class DisplayInvScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int X_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEMS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, Y_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEMS;

    public GameObject prefab;

    public Inventory inventory;

    Dictionary< InventorySlot, GameObject> itemsDisplayed = new Dictionary<InventorySlot, GameObject>();

    public int x_START, Y_START;

    
    void Start()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Container.Count; i++){
            var obj = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, quaternion.identity, transform);
            obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = GetPosition(i);


            Transform[] textlist = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            foreach (var thing in textlist){
                if (thing.name == "Item Name")
                {
                    thing.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].item.idName;
                } 
                else if (thing.name == "Item Amt")
                {
                    thing.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].amount.ToString();
                } 
                else if (thing.name == "Item Type")
                {
                    thing.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].item.type.ToString();
                } else { }
            }

            itemsDisplayed.Add(inventory.Container[i],obj);

        }

    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Container.Count; i++){
            if(itemsDisplayed.ContainsKey(inventory.Container[i])){

                Transform[] testlist = itemsDisplayed[inventory.Container[i]].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

                foreach (var thing in testlist){

                    if (thing.name == "Item Amt")
                    {
                        thing.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].amount.ToString();
                    } 
                    else { }
                }

            }
            else {
                var obj = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, quaternion.identity, transform);
                obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = GetPosition(i);
                 

                Transform[] textlist = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

                foreach (var thing in textlist){
                    if (thing.name == "Item Name")
                    {
                        thing.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].item.idName;
                    } 
                    else if (thing.name == "Item Amt")
                    {
                        thing.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].amount.ToString();
                    } 
                    else if (thing.name == "Item Type")
                    {
                        thing.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].item.type.ToString();
                    } else { }
                }
                itemsDisplayed.Add(inventory.Container[i],obj);
            }
        }
    }
    

    public Vector3 GetPosition(int i){
        return new Vector3(x_START + (X_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEMS * (i % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)),Y_START + (-Y_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEMS*(i/NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)),0f);
    }
}


Tried instantiating it differently and even changing the pivot of the object but nothing seems to work.

I think only one of your images got uploaded, you said that "top was in the inventory before running and the second during play."

As “in top item in inventory”, it’s been edited to be more clear :)

can you upload the image before it enter play mode? so we can compare the layout before n after play mode.

It’s not visible outside play mode as the elements are generated either on start or on update. It’s whether the item is added to the ui during either of those steps when I see the difference in alignment.
